# Cassandra: I see ALTER TABLE ... in the logs but why ? Is it Cassandra internal

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, phantom-dsl

I am monitoring a system, and in Cassandra I see lots of

> ALTER TABLE tbl-name ADD column-name type

The legacy code I am going through I cannot see any ALTER TABLE
So either Cassandra is synchronising somehow between nodes
OR I have people in my env doing funky stuff

Any ideas how to figure out from where these ALTER commands are coming from ?

Using Cassandra 3.11, Scala, and Phantom DSL 1.28

Comment: what are the table and column names? have you done upgrade recently?

Comment: Although I now KNOW who did this, as someone raised their hand ...
It still would be interesting to get some details on how to figure out from where certain calls comes from.

Comment: @TobiasEriksson You are on a very very old version of phantom we don't really support anymore. However, you should still have configurable logging, and that logging at least in phantom is per table. If you have alter queries in phantom, then you can easily search for `table.alter` in whatever codebase is doing the writes.